# What is the image of the box defined by the equations $−1 ≤ x ≤ 1, 0 < y ≤ π$ under the transformation $.f(z) = e^z$

Tags: complex-analysis

What is the image of the box defined by the equations $−1 ≤ x ≤ 1, 0 < y ≤ π$ under the transformation 
$.f(z) = e^z$

**My attempt**: equations given: $−1 ≤ x ≤ 1 \rightarrow −1 ≤ Re(z) ≤ 1$ and  $0 < y ≤ π \rightarrow 0 < Im(z) ≤ π$,  $e^z=e^{x+iy}=e^xe^{iy}=e^x(cos(y)+isin(y))$

I am aware that given a line segment $Re(z) = a$;  $e^z=e^{a+iy}=e^ae^{iy}=e^a(cos(y)+isin(y))$ maps under $e^z$ to the circle $|z|=e^a$, where positive $a$ values map to circles outside the unit disc and negative $a$ values map to circles inside the unit disc. Given $-π < y ≤ π$.

So in this case, would the box be mapped to a semi-circular regions between $Re(z)=-1$ and $Re(z)=1$ since 
$0 < y ≤ π$
i.e image of the box for negative $x$ values are mapped to a semi-circular region of the unit disc and the positive values being mapped to a semi-circular region outside the unit disc. And for $x=0$ no values are sent to the origin??

Any assistance on this would be great. If anyone needs me to clarify my thought process I will do so if needed as it may seem confusing to others. I hope what I have claimed is somewhat true although I am still a novice when it comes to complex analysis. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $z=x+iy$. Since $e^z=e^x(\cos y + i \sin y)$, we have
$$|e^z|=e^{\Re(z)}=e^x$$

and

$$\text{Arg}(e^z)=e^{\Im(z)}=e^y.$$

By the monotonicity of the real exponential function

$$e^{-1}\le |e^z| \le e^1$$

and

$$0 \le \text{Arg}(e^z) \le \pi.$$

Therefore, the image of the box looks like a quarter of a planar donut.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are welcome. :)